# VC++ - How to get permission to write on NTFS boot sector?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli, ntfs-mft

I searched a lot to get write - access to the boot sector (Master File Table ). I used `CreateFile` function with write access parameters like, `GENERIC_WRITE`. Then used `SetFilePointer` and `WriteFile` to write on a particular memory address. But what I always get is `System.AccessViolationException` (Windows 7). Am I doing something wrong here ?

I want to know if there is any alternative to CreateFile - WriteFile functions to get wrtie - access to boot sector ?

OR I was thinking if there is any way to use Interrup Service Routine to write on particular disk sectors in VC++ (C++/Cli) ?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/279229/Code-in-C-to-Access-the-master-boot-record-MBR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100027) you have to call `CreateFile` with `FILE_SHARE_READ` and `FILE_SHARE_WRITE` on `"\\.\PhysicalDriveN"`, where `N` is zero-based physical drive index. Then you can access the entire drive as one huge file. You have to be an **administrator** on your machine for this to work!

> You can open a physical or logical drive using the `CreateFile()`
>   application programming interface (API) with these device names
>   provided that you have the appropriate access rights to the drive
>   (that is, you must be an administrator). You must use both the
>   `CreateFile()` `FILE_SHARE_READ` and `FILE_SHARE_WRITE` flags to gain access
>   to the drive.
>
> Once the logical or physical drive has been opened, you can then
>   perform direct I/O to the data on the entire drive. When performing
>   direct disk I/O, you must seek, read, and write in multiples of sector
>   sizes of the device and on sector boundaries. Call DeviceIoControl()
>   using IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY to get the bytes per sector,
>   number of sectors, sectors per track, and so forth, so that you can
>   compute the size of the buffer that you will need.

**Update:** I did some research and I found out that starting Vista you have to obtain the lock on the volume or dismount it. Otherwise the writes would fail.  In [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365747%28VS.85%29.aspx) Microsoft says:

> If you write directly to a volume that has a mounted file system, you
>   must first obtain exclusive access to the volume. Otherwise, you risk
>   causing data corruption or system instability, because your
>   application's writes may conflict with other changes coming from the
>   file system and leave the contents of the volume in an inconsistent
>   state. To prevent these problems, the following changes have been made
>   in Windows Vista and later:
>
> A write on a volume handle will succeed if the volume does not have a mounted file system, or if one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - The sectors to be written to are boot sectors.
> - The sectors to be written to reside outside of file system space.
> - You have explicitly locked or dismounted the volume by using `FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME` or `FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME`.
> - The volume has no actual file system. (In other words, it has a RAW file system mounted.)
>
> A write on a disk handle will succeed if one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - The sectors to be written to do not fall within a volume's extents.
> - The sectors to be written to fall within a mounted volume, but you have explicitly locked or dismounted the volume by using `FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME` or `FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME`.
> - The sectors to be written to fall within a volume that has no mounted file system other than RAW.

Comment: About your update: that says you don't need to lock/dismount the volume if you're only writing boot sectors, as long as you're writing through a volume handle, does it not?

Comment: @hvd, there's not enough information in the original question. It's not clear of OP is opening a volume or a physical drive. He could also be writing into some other area by mistake. It's easy to lock the volume and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Sure, although I don't see how attempting to write to the file system data can result in an `AccessViolationException`: that almost certainly indicates an incorrect use of pointers.

Comment: I say, this is the best and exact answer to my problem, which is solved now. Thanks @detunized